# Using external files for nodejs

Tags: node.js, package.json

I faced a problem with adjusting paths for my project. The project has following structure:

```
prj
 |-common
 |   |-types
 |      |-somefile.ts ...
 |
 |-server
 |   |-node_modules
 |   |-package.json ...
 |
 |-client
 |   |-node_modules
 |   |-package.json
 |   |-angular.json ...
```

somefile.ts

```
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs'; !!!Cannot find module 'rxjs' or its corresponding type declarations
export class Someclass {}
```

As you may see i want to reuse common types between server and client side. **somefile.ts** is easily imported in project via relative path. But when the **somefile.ts** is used in some of the project, popups error for "rxjs" module.

How to properly configure package.json for projects?

Comment: It's very bad practice to use modules from other project folders, what if that folder updates it's dependencies and breaks your project? keep your projects modules seperate.

Comment: i am not going to use in client project types from server side. that what you mean. 
It is quite widespread to use COMMON libraries/types between projects which intend to be used for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

If it’s not a core module (you installed it), you need to give a path to `node_modules` folder. Which I can see there’s two.
You need to make sure which one of them contains `rxjs`.
Then give the path like this:

```js
const rxjs = require("../../server/node_modules/rxjs");
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I thought about similar solution. Probably i will use it if i do not find more elegant one. Unfortunately this approach, will not work if projects have a different folder levels(NOT my case). that is why, i am looking for more universal solution.